# How to optimize svg loading? Next.js (app)

Tags: reactjs, svg, optimization, next.js

I want to use svg sprite in my Next.js (app folder) application. I created this component

```
const Icon = ({ type = 'main', name = '', color = '#000', size = '24', className }: IconProps) => {
    return (
        <svg width={size} height={size} fill={color} className={className}>
            <use href={`/assets/images/sprites/${type}.svg#${name}`} />
        </svg>
    )
```

but I ran into a problem that when routing, every time a request occurs for a whole sprint, which affects badly performance. Even if I return to an already loaded route, then again there is a request for a sprint

can you suggest articles on how best to work with sprint svg in an application. thanks

[image]

Comment: I would say this is probably caused by some misconfiguration on your server. What are you using for serving these files, and does your server return the proper caching headers?

Comment: Now all sprites are in the public folder (/public/assets/images/sprites/)

Comment: Is the issue occurring in developer mode or in production build?

Comment: in build it's more visible to the eye ( icons while loading flicker)